# VS 2022 Cannot Validate to GitHub - using localhost?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2022

Trying to validate my VS2022 with GitHub, but when I do it fails because it redirects to localhost, which makes no sense.

Anyone else ever encountered this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have it all the time; I gave up and use the token (another option), and then it works